# Gulp-sourcemaps rewrite mappingUrl

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-sourcemaps

When I write the sourcemap of a file like this:

```
 gulp.src(paths.scripts.js.input)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.js.dir));
```

it writes in my .js `//# sourceMappingURL=Input.js.map` each time the .map is generated.

Is there a way to rewrite the first sourceMappingUrl instead of adding one over and over?

**EDIT:**

I added the comment in all my .js files and disabled the "addComment" property in gulp-sourcemaps. It works but it's just a workaround.

Comment: I was getting multiple sourceMappingUrl's for a while too.  What version of gulp-sourcemaps are you using, latest is 2.6.1 ?

Comment: Sorry for late answer, I am using gulp-sourcemaps 2.6.1